# Boogie Woogie Verbing

Tags: ing, music, verbing

I'm writing a caption for a cartoon using the musical genre "Boogie Woogie" as a verb.

Which do you think is the most correct? Which is most clearly understandable?

a) Boogie-woogie-ing
b) Boogie Woogie-ing
c) Boogie Woogieing
d) boogie-woogying

Comment: Probably _boogying woogie_ :-)

Comment: I'd go (a) or (d).

Comment: @JohnLawler : Lords Chancellor, Trades Union and Boogies Woogie? :-)

Answer (score 2):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) tries to stay out of the fray by treating *boogie-woogie* strictly as a noun. But its entry for *boogie* as a verb is instructive:

> **boogie** *also* **boogy** *or* **boogey** *vi* **boogied** *also* **boogeyed**; **boogying** *also* **boogeying** (1930) 1 : to dance to rock music; also : REVEL, PARTY **2 a :** to move  quickly **b :** to get going

The most interesting thing about this entry isn't the definitions; it's the handling of the inflected forms. You could go with the consistent series of forms *boogey*, *boogeyed*, and *boogeying*, or the fairly straightforward series *boogy*, *boogied*, *boogying*. But how does *boogie* work—*boogie*, *boogied*, *boogying*? That last form is both unusual and unexplained.

In any case, what holds for *boogie* as a verb can reasonably be used as guidance for *boogie-woogie* as a verb. So if *boogie-ing* and *boogieieng* are unsupported, we can hardly expect *woogie-ing* and *woogieing* to pass muster. The Eleventh Collegiate is clear that initial caps for *Boogie* and *Woogie* are not called for, which takes care of options (a), (b), and (c) already, leaving us with (d) *boogie-woogying* as the the last boogie-woogier standing.

I suppose that that's the best we can do, given that the Eleventh Collegiate doesn't list any alternative spellings for the noun *boogie-woogie*; but if someone were to decide that the *y* in *woogying* cried out too pitifully for a matching *y* in *boogy*, I wouldn't oppose the move very strenuously. Between *boogie-woogying* and *boogy-woogying*, you can surely make a choice that won't ruin any reader's day.

Comment: +1, but I'd take this a step further and argue that boogie **is** the verb form of Boogie woogie.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to verb Boogie Woogie, I wouldn't change it except insofar as you need to in order to verb it. Because it's a bit of a mouthful, I'd clarify as you've done in (b).